# Анимация кнопки в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Сделал анимацию на кнопку, но не работает. Помогите пожалуйста с данной проблемой, т.к только неделю назад начал всем этим делом заниматься.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Анимация привязана на кнопку PlayButton, но не работает. Если возможно, объясните поподробнее как в данной ситуации нужно создавать анимацию.(кнопка располагается в рамке снизу)

Comment: Простой алгоритм,который тебе всегда поможет,программируешь ты либо пишешь игру на юнити: 1.пишешь свою проблему в гугл 2.открываешь первые 3 ссылки 3.если не помогло или лень читать, то тоже самое делаешь на ютубе,там море инфы по основам юнити

Comment: В том то и проблема, что я не смог найти :/